# What's the basic concept behind rails' act_as?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can't seem to find the answer to this,
I somewhat *see* what it does through implementation, but don't grok the sense of it..

Comment: What do you mean "basic concept behind"? It's a way to reuse code through predictable and reusable functionality via metaprogramming.

Comment: Before I made an editing mistake, do you mean 'gork' or 'grok'?

Comment: grok of course. "to share the same semiosphere or line of thinking with another physical or conceptual entity"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [article](http://web.archive.org/web/20121114165240/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-cb03137/index.html) explains the `acts_as` plugin architecture using the `acts_as_state_machine` plugin as an example.

Answer (score 3):

Yehuda Katz has a [nice explanation](http://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/12/better-ruby-idioms/) of the *acts_as* plugin pattern and why it's usually implemented in a needlessly complicated way.